# android remote python scripting in vim

Tags: android, python, vim

I am aware that you can 'remotely' script android using port forwarding, using the following:

```
adb forward tcp:9999 tcp:<android port no>
export AP_PORT=9999
```

and then in python2.6:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import android
>>> droid = android.Android()
>>> droid.makeToast("this works")
Result(id=0, result=None, error=None)
```

this works fine, but then I thought about trying it with VIM (macVim). the idea being that I could use:

```
map <buffer> <S-e> :w<CR>:!/usr/bin/python2.6 % <CR>
```

in my .vimrc to run the code I am editing. This works fine for testing python scripts on the mac. But when trying it with the android I get the following if i try the run this (saved as and.py):

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
droid.makeToadt("hihi")


:!/usr/bin/python2.6 and.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "and.py", line 2, in <module>
    droid = android.Android()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/android.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.conn = socket.create_connection(addr)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 498, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I am presuming that the export AP_PORT=9999 is not 'visible' to vim as the problem seems to be in creating the `self.conn` . any ideas? Does anyone use this approach?

I am not using the emulator as my computer is toooooo slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable in vim's environment. Use:

```
:let $AP_PORT=9999
```

to set it - this will be inherited by the python sub-process you're spawning.

Comment: brilliant - I had been trying to declare it in the script... can I add this to my vim.rc ? or would this case problems? when not using the android?

Comment: unless some other program happens to use that environment variable you should be fine putting it into your vimrc